# JQuery click event attaches to more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function that creates button elements in dialog header. However, the click event gets attached to all the buttons instead of current button.

```
_createTitlebarButtons : function(){
    for (var each in this.options.titlebarButtons ) {
        var self = this,
            props = this.options.titlebarButtons[each];


        if ( !props.icon ){ props.icon = ""}
        if ( !props.name ){ props.name = "button-"+each.toString()}
        if ( !props.click ){ props.click = function(){} }
        if ( !props.text ){ props.text = "" }

        var curButton = $( "<button type='button' id='btn-"+each+"' ></button>" ).button({
                type: "button",
                label: $( "<a>" ).text( props.text ).html(),
                icon: props.icon,
                showLabel: false
            })
            .attr("name", props.name)
            .css("right", 3+22*(Number(each)+1))
            .appendTo( this.uiDialogTitlebar )
            .on( "click", function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        props.click.apply( self.element[ 0 ], arguments );
                    });

        this._addClass( curButton, "ui-dialog-titlebar-close" );
    }
},
```

All the icons and classes work. However, the click event gets attached to all the buttons instead of one button. So if I have multiple buttons the click event is going to be the same for all buttons. And its going to be the click event of the last button. So:

```
titlebarButtons : [
        {   
            name: "button1",
            text: "tooltip",
            icon: "ui-icon-heart",
            click:function(){
                console.log("Button1 Clicked");
                console.log(this);
            }
        },
        {   
            name: "button2",
            text: "tooltip",
            icon: "ui-icon-close",
            click:function(){
                console.log("Button2 Clicked");
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    ]
```

Will create 2 buttons but on click they both will be saying "Button2 Clicked" whereas the first one should say "Button1 clicked".

EDIT: Had to use $.each instead of for loop because of scope problems.

```
$.each( this.options.titlebarButtons, function(index){
        console.log(this);

        var props = this;

        if ( !props.icon ){ props.icon = ""}
        if ( !props.name ){ props.name = "button-"+index}
        if ( !props.click ){ props.click = function(){} }
        if ( !props.text ){ props.text = "" }

        var curButton = $( "<button type='button' ></button>" ).button({
                type: "button",
                label: $( "<a>" ).text( props.text ).html(),
                icon: props.icon,
                showLabel: false
            })
            .attr("name", props.name)
            .css("right", 3+22*(Number(index)+1))
            .appendTo( self.uiDialogTitlebar )
            .on( "click", function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        props.click.apply( self.element[ 0 ], arguments );
                    });


        self._addClass( curButton, "ui-dialog-titlebar-close" );
    } )
```

Comment: In this case, might use `.click()` versus `.on("click")`. I have found the former to work better in these sorts of scenarios.

Comment: Scope - your 'self' is outside the loop, so gets changed to the last element of the loop by the time the click event is called.  "But it's declared inside the loop" you say - maybe, but the scope is still outside as that's how JS variables work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ookwg8bq/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var uiDialog = {
    options: {
      titlebarButtons: [{
        name: "button1",
        text: "tooltip",
        icon: "ui-icon-heart",
        click: function() {
          console.log("Button1 Clicked");
          console.log(this);
        }
      }, {
        name: "button2",
        text: "tooltip",
        icon: "ui-icon-close",
        click: function() {
          console.log("Button2 Clicked");
          console.log(this);
        }
      }]
    },
    uiDialogTitlebar: "#uiDialogTitlebar",
    _createTitlebarButtons: function() {
      var self = this;
      $.each(self.options.titlebarButtons, function(ind, elem) {
        var props = self.options.titlebarButtons[ind];

        if (!props.icon) {
          props.icon = ""
        }
        if (!props.name) {
          props.name = "button-" + ind
        }
        if (!props.click) {
          props.click = function() {}
        }
        if (!props.text) {
          props.text = ""
        }

        var curButton = $("<button>", {
            type: 'button',
            id: 'btn-' + ind,
            name: props.name,
            class: "ui-dialog-titlebar-close"
          }).button({
            type: "button",
            label: props.text,
            icon: props.icon,
            showLabel: false
          })
          .css("right", 3 + 22 * (ind + 1))
          .appendTo(self.uiDialogTitlebar)
          .click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            props.click.apply(elem, []);
          });
      });
    }
  };

  uiDialog._createTitlebarButtons();

});
```

This creates both buttons and you can click on each button. They sort of overlap due to the `right` styling. I get the following results in FireFox w/FireBug console:

```
Button1 Clicked
/_display/ (line 73)
Object { name="button1",  text="tooltip",  icon="ui-icon-heart",  more...}
/_display/ (line 74)
Button2 Clicked
/_display/ (line 81)
Object { name="button2",  text="tooltip",  icon="ui-icon-close",  more...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// trigger event when click on a button
$('button').on('click', function() {
    _createTitlebarButtons($(this));
};

// function called by the event
function _createTitlebarButtons(button) {
    // List all the actions that affect only the button you want to refer to it as "button". i.e:
    button._addClass( curButton, "ui-dialog-titlebar-close" );
};
```